# Magento price display issue (1.9.2) on products with custom options

Tags: custom-options, custom

I am facing a problem with Magento 1.9.2 which is puzzling. The price displays well on products without custom options (Sample on link)
https://tech-gear.com/kaiser-baas-alpha-drone

On products with custom options it is showing a decimal before the price...its like the website is dividing by 10,000 
https://tech-gear.com/shock-doctor-knee-sleeve

Please help

Comment: Links to your site don't help much to understand what's wrong. Please show the configuration of the custom options and what outcome you would expect from it.

Comment: Impossible to diagnose without knowing the code, so putting on hold. Looks like you have JS and HTTPS issues. Switch back to a standard Magento theme to start diagnosis. Update your question once you get some particulars and we can reopen.